# Como implementar um "listener" em um vídeo?

Tags: redirecionamento, vídeo, html5-video, listener, event-listener

Bem, eu tenho um botão e ao clicar nele, ele irá chamar uma função que abra uma página com um vídeo em fullscreen com autoplay="true". ACONTECE QUE, após o término do vídeo preciso redirecionar o usuário para uma outra página html. Alguém pode me indicar um caminho para implementar esse script? Penso que seria uma espécie de 'listener', mas não faço ideia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe uma propriedade dos vídeos em HTML 5 que é capaz de detectar se o vídeo acabou ou não.

Para sanarmos sua dúvida acho que poucas linhas de código são necessárias

```
 //caso o vídeo tenha acabado o retorno é true, caso não será false
   document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);

    function myHandler(e) {
        window.location.href = "http://pt.stackoverflow.com";    
    }
```

Link Útil

[Detectar final de vídeo](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_ended.asp)

Comment: Realmente caiu como uma luva e alcançou o objetivo. Obrigado pela força. Cada vez mais amando 'programação'.

Comment: Que ótimo! Qualquer coisa é só perguntar.